# how should to implement correctly a constructor of a class with stls inside

Tags: c++, constructor

hey I i am writing a Program in C++ and for some reason the compiler finds errors , and cant find my constructor: here is my class: (inside a h file)

```
class Adjutancy
{
private:
 vector<Vehicale*,CompareCatId>* m_vehicalesVector;
 map<const string,Base*>* m_baseMap;
 map<const int,City*>* m_citiesMap;
 vector<vector<Distance*>>* m_distancesMatrix;
public:

 Adjutancy(vector<Vehicale*,CompareCatId>* vehicalesVector , map<const string,Base*>* baseMap , map<const int,City*>* citiesMap , vector<vector<Distance*>>* distancesMatrix);
};
```

and here is my constructor implementation inside a cpp file:
sorry about the length of it.

```
Adjutancy::Adjutancy(vector<Vehicale*,
  CompareCatId>* vehicalesVector,map<const string,Base*>* baseMap,
  map<const int,City*>* citiesMap,
  vector<vector<Distance*>>* distancesMatrix):
      m_vehicalesVector(vehicalesVector),
      m_baseMap(baseMap),
      m_citiesMap(citiesMap),
      m_distancesMatrix(distancesMatrix)
{}
```

for some reason inside my main i cant use the constructor.
thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the calling code in main and the erros (and please format your code so that it is readable - I have made an attempt)

Comment: and what is `CompareCatId`? this one should be the allocator type

Comment: sorry about that and i just cant get the constructor to work it makes a red line below paranthesses that are next to the Adjustancy:
Adjutancy* adjutancy = new Adjutancy(vehicalesVector,baseMap,citiesMap,distancesMatrix);

Comment: How do you create the object in main?

Comment: Adjutancy* adjutancy = new Adjutancy(vehicalesVector,baseMap,citiesMap,distancesMatrix);
for some reason it doesnt recognize the constructor

Comment: @Nadav: Assuming `CompareCatId` is a comparison function, then that's one problem: `vector` doesn't compare objects, and its second (optional) template parameter is a memory allocator. Also, your compiler may not like the two `>>` without a space in between.

Comment: @Nadav Stern: my bet is that you're passing arguments of wrong types to that ctor you have posted in your snippet. it'll be appreciated if you just copy&paste the error you got from your compiler

Comment: What is an adjutancy ? and a vehicale ?

Comment: some objects
Mike Seymour was right ... seems like the functor made a problem

Comment: and are you sure that i cannot put a functor inside a vector , my Proffesor taught me about it

Comment: @Nadav: Sorted containers, like `map` and `set`, can be given a functor to use to compare the objects - since they need to do that to store them in the correct order. Sequence containers have no reason to compare objects, so there are no template parameters for that. `vector` just has two template parameters; the object type, and (optionally) a memory allocator.

Comment: @Nadav Stern: sure you can put a functor in vector of proper type, e.g. `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you mean this setup:

```
// file adjutancy.h
// ... includes for all classes used below
// forward declarations are OK for pointers and references
class Adjutancy
{
public:
    Adjutancy(vector<Vehicale*,CompareCatId>* vehicalesVector , map<const string,Base*>* baseMap , map<const int,City*>* citiesMap , vector<vector<Distance*>>* distancesMatrix);

private:
    vector<Vehicale*,CompareCatId>* m_vehicalesVector;
    map<const string,Base*>* m_baseMap;
    map<const int,City*>* m_citiesMap;
    vector<vector<Distance*>>* m_distancesMatrix;
};

// file adjutancy.cpp
#include "adjutancy.h"
Adjutancy::Adjutancy(vector<Vehicale*,CompareCatId>* vehicalesVector,map<const string,Base*>* baseMap,map<const int,City*>* citiesMap,vector<vector<Distance*>>* distancesMatrix)
:   m_vehicalesVector(vehicalesVector),
    m_baseMap(baseMap),
    m_citiesMap(citiesMap),
    m_distancesMatrix(distancesMatrix)
{   }
```

This is horrible code, and for several reasons:

1. You're storing a pointer to `std::vector`s and `std::map`s in your class: just store the `vector`s and `map`s themselves, no pointers needed here. Alternatively, store a reference, but beware of the limitations (no un-initialized reference data members!).
2. You should avoid template type lists with `>>`, put a space between the two, or some compilers will misinterpret it as `operator>>`.
3. Do not use `using` statements in your header, instead, use the full namespace prefix.

**I can't say what's wrong (everything looks correct at first glance) until you show me your `main` (complete!) function and how you want to use your constructor.**

---

Better version:

```
// file adjutancy.h

#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
class Adjutancy
{
public:
    Adjutancy( std::vector<Vehicale*,CompareCatId> &vehicalesVector,
               std::map<const std::string,Base*> &baseMap,
               std::map<const int,City*> &citiesMap,
               std::vector<std::vector<Distance*> > &distancesMatrix );

private:
    std::vector<Vehicale*,CompareCatId> &m_vehicalesVector;
    std::map<const std::string,Base*> &m_baseMap;
    std::map<const int,City*> &m_citiesMap;
    std::vector<std::vector<Distance*> > &m_distancesMatrix;
};

// file adjutancy.cpp
#include "adjutancy.h"

#include <map>
    using std::map;
#include <string>
    using std::string;
#include <vector>
    using std::vector;

Adjutancy::Adjutancy( vector<Vehicale*, CompareCatId> &vehicalesVector,
                      map<const string, Base*> &baseMap,
                      map<const int, City*> &citiesMap,
                      vector<vector<Distance*> > &distancesMatrix )
:   m_vehicalesVector( vehicalesVector ),
    m_baseMap( baseMap ),
    m_citiesMap( citiesMap ),
    m_distancesMatrix( distancesMatrix )
{   }
```

Also remember: "vehicle" is the correct English spelling.